# Bathroom sink overflow leak

Tags: bathroom, leak, sink, overflow

I recently replaced the drain in my bathroom sink. Shortly after, it began leaking from the overflow, right where that brown spot is. It looks like it’s been patched in the past, can this be patched again, or am I looking at a new sink? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: It is low pressure, so patching is possible.  Will need to clean off the old patching and get a nice clean surface, no paint/dirt/oils/slime.  Will need to find the material the sink is made of for the best patching/sealing product.  Most are a ceramic product.

Answer (score 2):

That one is in a sad shape.

Patching will be a problem since you have to work upside down and no patch material will flow into the crack.

You will end up with surface coverage only, which if you are lucky might seal it.

Meanwhile you can try some silicone.

Answer (score 2):

Any patch will only be very temporary.

If you don't want the sink to be a reoccurring problem, replace it.